# How to perform DFS or BFS when the edge list is given?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

How can I perform DFS or BFS when only an edge list is given?

I know how to do it when adjacency list or adjacency matrix is given and I also know how to convert edge list to adjacency list or adjacency matrix, But I wanna do DFS or BFS straight from the edge list.

`[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[1,4],[1,5]]`

Comment: 1) Mark the current vertex visited. 2) Search linearly for each edge terminating at the current vertex. 3) Follow said edges, unless they are already visited. Storing the graph in a different way (adjacency list, etc) will result in a much faster step 2.

Comment: 4) Don't SHOUT at us 5) Don't tell volunteers to do anything for you ASAP.

Comment: @Welbog So I think its better to convert edge list to adj. list, right?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a directed graph, you can sort the edge list by source edge, and then make a map of the starting or ending position in the list for each source.  You effectively get an adjacency list representation without recreating the whole data structure.

The sort can be done in O(N) time with an in-place counting sort like this one: [Counting sort implementation that modifies the input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862207/counting-sort-implementation-that-modifies-the-input-array/67863200#67863200), which conveniently produces the map of ending positions as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks, i guess this will make the solution way too complex.